# Import a Coingecko table to Google Spread Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to import the TOP LOOSERS table from this page to a Google Spreadsheet but I have no idea whatsoever how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data by this way, i.e in D2

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.coingecko.com/fr","table",1)
```

but it is difficult to order the result since values are in string format including %. You can then compute in A3, with % format in column B

```
=query(arrayformula({F3:F,1*(J3:J)}),"select * order by Col2 limit 10")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZSonplM0DqXBaggACVo906AYz1ys9k_xrDzogb-k0sQ/copy